# How to convert to LINQ Queries

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

i want to convert the below for loops into a LINQ query. 
What i am doing is adding the list of values into a dictionary by using for loop.
Now i want them to be executed by using LINQ Queries.
Can any one help me in doing that as i am beginner to c#.

```
           foreach (var item in allContainedDeals)
            {
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();

                var listOfValuesInDeal = item.Split(',').ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < listOfValuesInDeal.Count; i++)
                    {
                    if(!dict.ContainsKey(fieldSequence[i]))
                            dict.Add(fieldSequence[i], listOfValuesInDeal[i]);
                    }

                foreach (var pair in dict)
                {
                    if (input.DealInputs.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
                    {
                        input.DealInputs[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Why do you want to convert it?

Comment: And at least give us code that will compile. This is missing an end `}` and we have no idea what the variables `allContainedDeals`, `fieldSequence` or `input` are.

Comment: there is nothing wrong but i want the same to be implemented using LINQ Queries as per req.

Comment: the variables allContainedDeals,fieldSequence contains list of values

Comment: @VijayBabu Come on, give us some information we can use. Your response and question are very lazy. I want to help but with this info it's impossible.

Comment: Linq isn't [magic](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/). It doesn't do stuff "faster" or necessarily "better". It's basically just a bunch of extension methods that in most (not all) cases let you express what you want to do in fewer characters. If you just want to learn how to work with Linq, you should start by looking at examples on how to use the "simpler" methods like `Where`, `Select` and `OrderBy` and go from there to the more "complicated" ones like `ToDictionary` and so on. -- just using Linq for the sake of using Linq feels like the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
foreach (var pair in dict.Where(pair => input.DealInputs.ContainsKey(pair.Key)))
{
    input.DealInputs[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
}
```